# Dump Values in JSON in a file with specified Key

Tags: python, json

I am using Pandas Dataframe filters to get data from a JSON file.

Ultimately that data gets stored in a variable named "sects" as a JSON, and then dumped into a file.

What I want to do is, Dump that variable named "sects" to the file as a Value in pair as a

```
{"Key": "Value"}
```

For which I want to define the Key as the name of the variable ie "sects".

So the variable "sects" looks like this:

```
{"abc":"xyz","qwe":"rty","qww":"yte"}
```

and the expected output is:

```
{"sects": {"abc":"xyz","qwe":"rty","qww":"yte"}}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a dictionary first with the inner dictionary key, values like this

`value={"abc":"xyz","qwe":"rty","qww":"yte"}`

and then assign this to dictionary key

`{"sects": value }`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood properly what you actually want to achieve but why not something like this -

```
import json

x = {"abc":"xyz","qwe":"rty","qww":"yte"}
final_data = {}
final_data['sects'] = x
with open('test.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(final_data))
```

Does this solve your problem?